# How could I bind `save` method using `Q` with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, q

Saying that I have the following schema in `User.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Q = require('q');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
    index: {
      unique: true
    }
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports.findOne = Q.nfbind(module.exports.findOne.bind(module.exports));
module.exports.find = Q.nfbind(module.exports.find.bind(module.exports));
```

And another file `testuser.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Q = require('q');
var User = require('../User');

var connectionStr = "mongodb://localhost:27017/user-model-test";
mongoose.connect(connectionStr, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    throw(error);
  }
  console.log("Connect to MongoDB...");
  var testuser = new User({
    phone: 1008611,
  });
  testuser.save = Q.nfbind(testuser.save.bind(testuser));
  testuser.save().then(function () {
    return User.findOne({ phone: 1008611 }).then(function (user) {
      console.log(user.phone);
      mongoose.disconnect();
    }, function (error) {
      throw(error);
    });
  }, function (error) {
    throw(error);
  }).done();
});
```

Notice that currently I use `testuser.save = Q.nfbind(testuser.save.bind(testuser));` to bind the `save`, but I want to do it in `User.js`, like `module.exports.find = Q.nfbind(module.exports.find.bind(module.exports));`, is there any way that I could do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on Q, I'd do something like:

```
User.create = function(data){
    var u = new User(data);
    u.save = Q.nfbind(testuser.save.bind(testuser));
    // add other methods you want
    return u;
};
```

However, I'd like to add that all other Mongoose methods already return a promise if you call `.exec()` on them (so `.find(..).exec()` returns an mpromise promise). That is, Mongoose already provides a promise API, `save` is one of the only methods that are not included yet [and there are plans to include it](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1431).

It's also beneficial to know that this becomes a one liner with Bluebird, which has a `promisifyAll` function that creates promises that are easier to debug and are faster than Qs or Mongoose's.